# String and variable concatenation in php

Tags: php, concatenation

I am new to PHP and I want to concatenate a string with a variable without any space. I am using a variable `$var` and a string which is given below.

```
$var   // This is variable
"Name\branch" //This is String
```

I want to concatenate the string and the variable without any space. I am using code like this:

```
$var2 = "Name\Branch\ $var"
```

But a space is created between them.

Answer (score 8):

Space is there, because you entered it ;)

Use examples:

```
$var2 = "Name\Branch\\$var";
$var2 = "Name\Branch\\" . $var;
$var2 = 'Name\Branch\\' . $var;
$var2 = "Name\Branch\\{$var}";
$var2 = trim("Name\Branch\ ") . $var;
```

Comment: In the first one it is taking $var as a string but the second one is working properly. Thanx for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.` for concatenations:

```
$var2 = "Name\\branch\\".$var;
```

Refer to [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: The backslash is escaping your end quote.

Answer (score 2):

this will help u

```
$var1 = 'text';
$var2 = "Name&#92;branch&#92;".$var1;
```

o/p: Name\branch\text

Answer (score 1):

You can use { } to use variable's value in a string.

```
$result = "Name\Branch\\{$var}";
```

Comment: However, only with double quotes string

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code : 
concatenation $var and $str using dot(.)

```
 $var = 'variable';
 $newvar = "Name\\Branch\\".$var
```

Comment: The backslash is escaping your end quote.

Answer (score -2):

use

```
$var2 = "Name\Branch\".$var;
```

Comment: The backslash is escaping your end quote.

Comment: @Glavić:having error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /tmp/execpad-ff70b37edf4d/source-ff70b37edf4d on line 3

Comment: @BenFortune:that is issue in his string not in variable concatication

Comment: @BenFortune:he asked for String and variable concatenation in php

Comment: @Glavić:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'BU' (T_STRING) in /tmp/execpad-f2a917aad30c/source-f2a917aad30c on line 5

Comment: @Glavić:that is your code,you better know it why is the error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41113/discussion-between-vishal-shah-and-glavic)